# Show a QWidget in win32 MDI area

Tags: qt, winapi, mdi

I am trying to extend a legacy win32 application functionalities. The legacy application has a Multiple Document Interface(MDI) as it's main window and is purely written in win32 API. Is it possible to show a QWidget in win32 MDI area as a child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using MFC?

What's important to understand is that running Qt always requires you have a running Qt event loop. So what you need is to properly process your MFC/win32 events an the Qt events.

There is the Qt solution [QtWinMigrage](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate) for that supports Qt 4 and Qt >= 5.4 (Qt 5.0-5.3 are broken). [Examples](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/tree/master/qtwinmigrate/examples) also show your use case.

This is certainly a good starting point if your application is based on CWinApp.

Further details can be found by searching the internet and reading about the [QAbstractEventDispatcher](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracteventdispatcher.html). Hope this helps!